# Is it possible to access call log using mobile website?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website, calllog, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a progressive website concept and trying to incorporate few concepts. Is it possible to access recent call log using a mobile progressive web application (like flipkart lite). If it is, please share an example if available.

Comment: If you redefine `console` object globally, you can do whatever you want. But to ask for example, you first need to describe the problem in detail. Please try to [follow the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot access the list of calls made and received. I'm  not aware of any spec work to enable this in the future either.